# Regex wont replace exact match with boundary condition

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to make a regex expression much like a sed command in bash. to replace the exact match of "user-services-http" but this can exist else where as "user-services-http-two" as well and gets replace.

```
>>> f = "'value: http://ec2-35-171-57-57.compute-1.amazonaws.com:32370ssoeproxy/logout    value: http://ec2-35-171-57-57.compute-1.amazonaws.com:user-services-http-two/ssoeproxy/logout  value: user-services-http #458930'"
>>> re.sub(r'\buser-services-http$', '11111', f)'value: http://ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:user-services-http/ssoeproxy/logout    value: http://ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:user-services-http-two/ssoeproxy/logout'
>>> re.sub(r'\buser-services-http\b', '11111', f)
'value: http://ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:11111/ssoeproxy/logout    value: http://ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:11111-two/ssoeproxy/logout'
```

Comment: Would simply adding a `/` to the end, ie searching for `user-services-http/`, work?

Comment: Thats really close, but that would replace the any / that came after the search string like a url. .com:11111ssoeproxy/logout

Comment: @Bohemian i updated the value of f

Answer (score 0):

You could use a negative look ahead like this:

```
import re

f = "value: http://ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:user-services-http/ssoeproxy/logout    value: http://ec2-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:user-services-http-two/ssoeproxy/logout"
print(re.sub(r'\buser-services-http\b(?!-[^/]+)/', '11111', f)
```

Output:

```
value: http://ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:11111/ssoeproxy/logout
value: http://ec2-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:user-services-http-two/ssoeproxy/logout
```

To make sure it's not followed by `-two` or other words.  This is done by using the negative character class `[^/]+`  A good place to try this stuff out is:

http://regex101.com

Comment: but what if there can be any string after it? That only solves the -two case, what about -three or "/" or 6789?

Comment: Ah, I thought it was -two specifically, I've updated my answer